# Unknown exception raised by Wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am using WordPress for my blog site it was working fine and suddenly the site is showing this warning and my client don't want it.

I haven't installed any plugins nor changed any code so can anyone please help me find the solution

The warning is:

> Creating default object from empty value in /home3/howtosta/public_html/utmostcars.com/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 642

Comment: have a look here, see if it helps: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-homeleadfortpublic_html/

Answer (score 0):

open your wordpress wp-config.php file, then find

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

replace it with below code,

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Comment: This code is hiding that warning message not removing that warning completely but my client had given me a go so i'll give this answer +1